# Can adjective be used with passive voice like this?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

If I say: 'she is a forgiving person' but in the context that she is a person who screw up times to times but has a nice personality and that she should be forgiven, would that be correct? or at leat undestandable given the context?

Comment: It wouldn't often be used, but the sense you have in mind would be conveyed by [***a forgivable person***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+forgivable+person%22) (one deserving of forgiveness, not one who easily forgives others).

Comment: @Fumble, I would draw a distinction between someone who is *simply* forgivable and one who actually *deserves* to be forgiven—I would say pretty much every person is technically forgivable (though their actions may or may not be). Whether they deserve forgiveness is a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

No, that would not carry the meaning you want. Your intention would not be understandable.

A "forgiv**ing** person" is *a person who forgives*, not one who is themselves forgiven.

You could say:

- She deserves forgiveness.
- She is worthy of forgiveness.
- She deserves to be forgiven.
- She ought to be forgiven.
- She should get a second chance.

etc.